# Why is vba code for calling multi worksheet not working as expected after 7 worksheets?

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that gives the user an option of calling 1 of 7 worksheets in a workbook. The code does work as expected up to sheet number 7. When I add an additional sheet I, receive a Run time error code #13 type mismatch.  It hangs on `If MyValue = False Then`. I have checked the sheet numbers & the sheet names. Both are correct, & have also tried copy/past of the names. I am wondering if 7 worksheets is the maximum number of sheets allowed. I need to go to 9 worksheets if Possible. Here is the code with the additional sheet:

```
Sub First_Half_Reports()
   Dim MyValue
     Dim i As String

    'MsgBox prompt:="1st 6 Months of Reports?", Title:="Referral Workbook - Data Entry"
    i = MsgBox("Continue to 1st 6 Months of Reports?", vbYesNo, " Referral Workbook - Data Entry")

    If Not i = vbYes Then Exit Sub

    'First message shows in the body of the box, message 2 shows at the top of the box.
    Do
        MyValue = Application.InputBox("Only Click Ok or Cancel after your Selection!!!!!!!" & vbCrLf & _
                               "Enter 1 for October Report" & vbCrLf & _
                               "Enter 2 for November Report" & vbCrLf & _
                               "Enter 3 for December Report" & vbCrLf & _
                               "Enter 4 for January Report" & vbCrLf & _
                               "Enter 5 for February Report" & vbCrLf & _
                               "Enter 6 for March Report" & vbCrLf & _
                               "Enter 7 for 1st Quarter" & vbCrLf & _
                               "Enter 8 for 1st 6 Month Report", "Walk In Training Data Entry")
        ' Sub messaage box exit.
        If MyValue = False Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf (MyValue = 1) Or (MyValue = 2) Or (MyValue = 3) Or (MyValue = 4) Or (MyValue = 5) Or (MyValue = 6) Or (MyValue = 7) Or (MyValue = 8) Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            MsgBox "You have not made a valid entry.  Please try again.", vbInformation, "Referral Workbook - Data Entry"
        End If
    Loop    'Code to Execute When Condition = value_1
    Select Case MyValue
        Case 1
                     If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "Sheet45" Then
               ' The message below only shows when you are on the active sheet.
                        MsgBox "You are already on October Report!", vbInformation, "Referral Workbook - Data Entry"
                    Else
                        Sheets("October_Report").Activate
                        Range("A1").Select
                    End If
        'Code to Execute When Condition = value_2
        Case 2
                     If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "Sheet46" Then
               ' The message below only shows when you are on the active sheet.
                        MsgBox "You are already on November Report!", vbInformation, "Referral Workbook - Data Entry"
                    Else
                        Sheets("November_Report").Activate
                        Range("A1").Select
                    End If

        'Code to Execute When Condition = value_3
        Case 3
                     If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "Sheet54" Then
               ' The message below only shows when you are on the active sheet.
                        MsgBox "You are already on December Report!", vbInformation, "Referral Workbook - Data Entry"
                    Else
                        Sheets("WI_DT_1ST").Activate
                        Range("A1").Select
                End If
                'Code to Execute When Condition = value_4
       Case 4
                     If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "Sheet48" Then
               ' The message below only shows when you are on the active sheet.
                        MsgBox "You are already on January Report!", vbInformation, "Referral Workbook - Data Entry"
                    Else
                        Sheets("January_Report").Activate
                        Range("A1").Select
                End If
      'Code to Execute When Condition = value_5
       Case 5
                     If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "Sheet49" Then
               ' The message below only shows when you are on the active sheet.
                        MsgBox "You are already on February Report!", vbInformation, "Referral Workbook - Data Entry"
                    Else
                        Sheets("February_Report").Activate
                        Range("A1").Select
                End If
       'Code to Execute When Condition = value_6
       Case 6
                     If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "Sheet50" Then
               ' The message below only shows when you are on the active sheet.
                        MsgBox "You are already on March Report!", vbInformation, "Referral Workbook - Data Entry"
                    Else
                        Sheets("March_Report").Activate
                        Range("A1").Select
                End If
                'Code to Execute When Condition = value_7
       Case 7
                     If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "Sheet11" Then
               ' The message below only shows when you are on the active sheet.
                        MsgBox "You are already on 1st Quarter Report!", vbInformation, "Referral Workbook - Data Entry"
                    Else
                        Sheets("1St_Qtr").Activate
                        Range("A1").Select
                End If
       'Code to Execute When Condition = value_8
       Case 8
                     If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "Sheet43" Then
               ' The message below only shows when you are on the active sheet.
                        MsgBox "You are already on 1st 6 Month Report!", vbInformation, "Referral Workbook - Data Entry"
                    Else
                        Sheets("1st_6_Month_Report").Activate
                        Range("A1").Select
                End If

    End Select 
End Sub
```

Comment: My money is on `Select`, `Activate` and implicit references to the active worksheet and to the active workbook (heck, explicit ones as well). Qualify all those, remove all `Select` and `Activate`. Your code will be easier to follow, and overall more robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that  InputBox prompt can't accept more than 254 characters. This worked for me

```
 MyValue = Application.InputBox("Only Click Ok or Cancel after your Selection!!!!!!!" & vbCrLf & _
                           "Enter 1 for October" & vbCrLf & _
                           "Enter 2 for November" & vbCrLf & _
                           "Enter 3 for December" & vbCrLf & _
                           "Enter 4 for January" & vbCrLf & _
                           "Enter 5 for February" & vbCrLf & _
                           "Enter 6 for March" & vbCrLf & _
                           "Enter 7 for 1st Quarter" & vbCrLf & _
                           "Enter 8 for 1st 6 Month", "Walk In Training Data Entry")
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was not aware of the limitation. I checked further & you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your inputbox prompt text is too long. I believe it has a limit of 255 characters (current prompt is 277 characters), otherwise you will get an error. Additionally, you should be declaring the `MyValue` variable with the data it's going to hold, it looks like a `Byte` should do.

If you want to retain the exact formatting, I'd recommend changing this InputBox into a UserForm.

Here is working code just for the beginning portion.

```
Sub SOExample()
    Dim MyValue       As Byte
    Const InputBoxTxt As String = "Only Click Ok or Cancel after your Selection!" & vbCrLf & _
                                  "Enter 1 for Oct Report" & vbCrLf & _
                                  "Enter 2 for Nov Report" & vbCrLf & _
                                  "Enter 3 for Dec Report" & vbCrLf & _
                                  "Enter 4 for Jan Report" & vbCrLf & _
                                  "Enter 5 for Feb Report" & vbCrLf & _
                                  "Enter 6 for March Report" & vbCrLf & _
                                  "Enter 7 for 1st Quarter" & vbCrLf & _
                                  "Enter 8 for 1st 6 Month Report"

    MyValue = Application.InputBox(InputBoxTxt, "Walk In Training Data Entry")

    If MyValue = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf MyValue >= 1 Or MyValue <= 8 Then
        'Exit Do
    Else
        MsgBox "You have not made a valid entry.  Please try again.", _
                vbInformation, _
                "Referral Workbook - Data Entry"
    End If
End Sub
```